# Typescript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

Tags: typescript, any

I have this code that is returning an error that says :
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`

```
const communes: ICommune[] = _.filter(wilayasData, (commune) => commune.wilaya_code === wilaya.wilaya_code);
      Object.keys(communes).forEach((key) => {
        communes[key].commune = communes[key].commune_name_ascii;
        communes[key].commune_ar = communes[key].commune_name;
        communes[key].daira = communes[key].daira_name_ascii;
        communes[key].daira_ar = communes[key].daira_name;
        delete communes[key].commune_name_ascii;
        delete communes[key].commune_name;
        delete communes[key].daira_name_ascii;
        delete communes[key].daira_name;
      });
```

the ICommune is an interface that is formed as follows :

```
    commune_name_ascii?: string;
    commune_name?: string;
    commune_ar?: string;
    commune?: string;
    daira?: string
    daira_ar?: string
    daira_name_ascii?: string;
    daira_name?: string;
    wilaya_code?: string;
    wilaya_name_ascii?: string;
    wilaya_name?: string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made couple changes in the interface to be :

```
interface ICommune {
  commune_name_ascii?: string;
  commune_name?: string;
  commune_ar?: string;
  commune?: string;
  daira?: string
  daira_ar?: string
  daira_name_ascii?: string;
  daira_name?: string;
  wilaya_code?: string;
  wilaya_name_ascii?: string;
  wilaya_name?: string;
}
```

for the code I parsed the key as integer to be a number and meet the common index schema

```
      const communes: ICommune[] = _.filter(wilayasData, (commune) => commune.wilaya_code === wilaya.wilaya_code);
      Object.keys(communes).forEach((key) => {
        const k = parseInt(key, 10);
        console.log(k);
        console.log(key);
        communes[k].commune = communes[k].commune_name_ascii;
        communes[k].commune_ar = communes[k].commune_name;
        communes[k].daira = communes[k].daira_name_ascii;
        communes[k].daira_ar = communes[k].daira_name;
        delete communes[k].commune_name_ascii;
        delete communes[k].commune_name;
        delete communes[k].daira_name_ascii;
        delete communes[k].daira_name;
      });
```

or we can just get the index besides the key

````
        communes[index].commune = communes[index].commune_name_ascii;
        communes[index].commune_ar = communes[index].commune_name;
        communes[index].daira = communes[index].daira_name_ascii;
        communes[index].daira_ar = communes[index].daira_name;
        delete communes[index].commune_name_ascii;
        delete communes[index].commune_name;
        delete communes[index].daira_name_ascii;
        delete communes[index].daira_name;
      });```
````